# Alternative Landmark Observation Model for Fast SLAM using 3D Point Clouds

Tags: mobile-robot, slam, localization, particle-filter, robot-model

I am in the process of implementing a Fast-SLAM Algorithm as it is described in Chapter 13 of *Probabilistic Robotics by Thrun, Burgard and Fox* or this [publication by Thrun, Koller and Wegbreit](http://robots.stanford.edu/papers/montemerlo.fastslam-tr.pdf) however, using a 3D instead of a 2D laser scanner.

The pose-state described by my particles is $\boldsymbol{x}_{t} = [x, y, \theta]^{T}$ with $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$  and $\theta \in [-\pi, \pi]$. Note that the pose is fully parameterized using these values since I assume that the robot is moving on a perfectly planar surface.

I obtain a Pointcloud consisiting of $[ x, y, z ]^{T}$ points (in the Robots frame) and compute the [keypoints using the Open3D library](http://www.open3d.org/docs/latest/tutorial/geometry/iss_keypoint_detector.html).

Assuming that correspondences are given (irrelevant to my question), I could update my landmark states $\langle \boldsymbol{l}_{i},\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{i}\rangle$ one of two ways.

##### 1. Using the Range-Bearing Observation Model

This is the approach described in the works above: assuming that an observed keypoint is given by a range and (in 3D) two bearing angles $\boldsymbol{z}_{i} = [\rho, \phi, \psi]$, I would need transform both the landmark $\boldsymbol{l}_{i}$ and its corresponding keypoint observation $\boldsymbol{f}_{j}$ into the robots frame and compute the angles therein.

The jacobian of this observation model is rather large, which is why I will not detail it here. Most importantly, because computing the range involves the L2-Norm *this observation model is nonlinear w.r.t. the landmark coordinates*.

##### 2. Using a Position-based observation model

Given that both $\boldsymbol{l}_{i}$ as well as my observed keypoints $\boldsymbol{f}_{j}$ are given by their 3D-positions, I could just transform the landmark into the robots frame using

$\hat{\boldsymbol{f}}_{i} = \begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{R}(\theta)^{T} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} l_{i,x} - x \\ l_{i, y} - y\end{bmatrix} \\ l_{i,z}\end{bmatrix}$

with

$\boldsymbol{R}(\theta) = \begin{bmatrix}\cos{\theta} & -\sin{\theta} \\ \sin{\theta} & \cos{\theta}\end{bmatrix}$

and because this is just a linear transform w.r.t. $\boldsymbol{l}_{i}$, I can directly use

$\boldsymbol{H} = \begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{R}(\theta)^{T} & \boldsymbol{0}_{2 \times 1} \\ \boldsymbol{0}_{1 \times 2} & 1\end{bmatrix}$

to compute the Kalman-gain for the landmark state.

##### But, can I do it like this?

The second approach wouldn't require me to first convert *both* the obsereved keypoints and the landmarks into a range-bearing observation and make the computation of the observation models jacobian much easier *(and, I suppose, faster)*.

I have not come up with a reason as to not do this, yet I do not know how I would find out if it would make any difference. Approach no. 1 just seems more tedious and I suppose it originates on the assumption that the observed keypoints naturally arrive as range-bearing measurements, which they do not in my case.

Hopefully, my problem is clear. Please let me know if there is any information that's missing here.
If there is any material to support me in making this decision, I would greatly appreaciate that.

Thanks.